# Working with blender, which renders faster?

Tags: performance, render, blender

I'm a computer science student, and I have a homework about doing some 3D figures on blender, and also some 3D animations. I know that the render speed will depend on the parameters you choose, but the question is, as I have two laptop computers:

which of the following renders faster in blender:

-------Compaq Presario F700--------

- 4GB RAM
- AMD Athlon X2 1.9 GHz (64 bits)
- nVidia gForce (not sure the model but it is pretty old)
- Ubuntu 12.04

or

---------Acer Aspire 5742-6838----------

- 4GB RAM
- Intel Core i5 2.67GHz (64bits)
- Intel HD Graphics
- Windows 7

thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess nVidia works fast coz you can get a CUDA optimized blender build from graphicall.org(Guessing that you have a decent graphic card and you use cycles)

If your materials are not cycles materials and you are planning on using Blender internal(old) renderer, forget nVidia one, go for the system with maximum no. of CPUs and fastest CPU.